# How to backup and restore with tar in a software raid 10 configuration?

Tags: software-raid, tar, raid10, system-restore

I've successfully backed up and restored using tar with VPS that were not raided. Now I have a setup at my residence that requires raid, specifically raid-10. If I attempt to restore the tar it fails, first off extracting fails at /var/lib/lxcfs stating something along the lines of can't set UID or GUID to 0. Second fail is if I reboot, I get dropped into initramfs with an Alert! that the UUID can't be found.

I take it that reinstalling has changed the UUID, so am wondering if there's a set of --exclude= that I need to set, or if there's a cleaner way to go about this.

Command for backup is:

```
tar -cvpjf "$date".tar.bz2 --exclude=/"$date".tar.bz2 --exclude=/root/backup / --one-file-system
```

Process of restore involves reinstalling with same OS, then:

```
tar -xvpjf backup.tar.bz2 --numeric-owner
```

How to go about a successful restore using tar on a raid-10 setup in Ubuntu 16.04?